# Submit form to new window's frame

Tags: html, forms, request, submit, frame

I want a html-form to

1. open a new window (which contains 2 frames)
2. send the data of the form to one of these frames as a request

Is this possible? Currently, the form just opens a new window with and sends the request to the URL of the page that processes it. But what I want is that the new window that opens has two frames, one of which processes the form data.

I hope you understand my question and thank you for an answer.

Comment: u will use frames or iframes? it's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A**

you will need to use AJAX and make those steps:

1. Open new window
2. Send request by using AJAX
3. Get response
4. Put response to DIV in new window

**Option B**

you will need to create special html file that will be default page one of frame. next you will need to copy whole form with values of inputs to this file and trigger the submit. this way is without AJAX but it's more hmm.... twisted?

tell which option you prefere and then i can help you with code if you want of course

You can open and access new window by:

```
newWin = null;
newWin = open("page.html", 'win1')
if(newWin&&newWin.open&&!newWin.closed){
    newDiv=newWin.document.createElement("DIV")
    newWin.document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
    newWin.focus()
} else {
    alert("The window is not open")
}
```

Comment: I guess option A is more sophisticated, but how can I access the contents of the new window in JS?

Comment: I now have a problem that I can't access the frames within the new created window... I tried using the frame names as elements of the window or document, but I always get "null" or "undefined" - how can I access the frames?!

Comment: give each frame `name` and then try by `newWin.document.frames["frameName"]`

Comment: also please visit this great site: http://www.huntingground.freeserve.co.uk/webplus/webplus.htm <-- here u have a lot of examples that u need right now :)